# How do I login to a website prior to scraping data?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Before web scraping, I'm using the following code to login.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'https://www.footballoutsiders.com/user/login'
data = {
'username': 'username',
'password': 'password'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
response = s.post(login_url , data)
print(response.text)
```

I then do the following to view the table, but the cells are still locked.

```
index_page= s.get('https://www.footballoutsiders.com/stats/nfl/historical-lookup-by- 
week/2020/1/overall')

soup = BeautifulSoup(index_page.text, 'lxml')

table1 = soup.find('table')
table1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: inspect the website go to the network tab and tick the preserve log.Then log in... when it will redirect you it will show all of the get and post requests you will need to find the one that handles the post for your name and password.A good video tutorial to follow (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM50i7sKwwM)

Comment: @PanosoikoGr Thanks so much for your comment. I followed that video exactly and still seem to be getting the exact same result. I used `data=payload` since the site doesn't appear to be in json format. I also skipped the authorization because it doesn't appear a token is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the wrong data. It should be `'user`' and `'pass'`. Also, don't use BeautifulSoup to parse `<table>` tags (when you only need the content). `Pandas` can do that for you (uses bs4 under the hood).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.footballoutsiders.com/user/login?destination=home' 
login = {
'name': '123@email.com',
'pass': '54321',
'form_id': 'user_login_form',
'op': 'Login'}

s = requests.Session()
s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login)

index_page= s.get('https://www.footballoutsiders.com/stats/nfl/historical-lookup-by-week/2020/1/overall')
df = pd.read_html(index_page.text)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_markdown())
|    | Team   | W-L   |   Total DVOA | Total DVOA.1   |   Weighted DVOA | Weighted DVOA.1   |   Offense DVOA | Offense DVOA.1   |   Offense Weighted DVOA | Offense Weighted DVOA.1   |   Defense DVOA | Defense DVOA.1   |   Defense Weighted DVOA | Defense Weighted DVOA.1   |   Special Teams DVOA | Special Teams DVOA.1   |   Special Teams Weighted DVOA | Special Teams Weighted DVOA.1   |
|---:|:-------|:------|-------------:|:---------------|----------------:|:------------------|---------------:|:-----------------|------------------------:|:--------------------------|---------------:|:-----------------|------------------------:|:--------------------------|---------------------:|:-----------------------|------------------------------:|:--------------------------------|
|  0 | BAL    | 1-0   |            1 | 88.0%          |               1 | 88.0%             |              1 | 39.9%            |                       1 | 39.9%                     |              3 | -38.8%           |                       3 | -38.8%                    |                    2 | 9.4%                   |                             2 | 9.4%                            |
|  1 | NE     | 1-0   |            2 | 52.3%          |               2 | 52.3%             |              3 | 36.4%            |                       3 | 36.4%                     |              5 | -23.8%           |                       5 | -23.8%                    |                   25 | -7.9%                  |                            25 | -7.9%                           |
|  2 | JAX    | 1-0   |            3 | 38.0%          |               3 | 38.0%             |              4 | 35.8%            |                       4 | 35.8%                     |             13 | 0.5%             |                      13 | 0.5%                      |                    5 | 2.8%                   |                             5 | 2.8%                            |
|  3 | SEA    | 1-0   |            4 | 37.0%          |               4 | 37.0%             |              2 | 38.6%            |                       2 | 38.6%                     |             21 | 9.5%             |                      21 | 9.5%                      |                    3 | 7.8%                   |                             3 | 7.8%                            |
|  4 | PIT    | 1-0   |            5 | 36.0%          |               5 | 36.0%             |             14 | 6.5%             |                      14 | 6.5%                      |              2 | -39.0%           |                       2 | -39.0%                    |                   27 | -9.4%                  |                            27 | -9.4%                           |
|  5 | WAS    | 1-0   |            6 | 35.9%          |               6 | 35.9%             |             28 | -32.7%           |                      28 | -32.7%                    |              1 | -69.4%           |                       1 | -69.4%                    |                   13 | -0.8%                  |                            13 | -0.8%                           |
|  6 | BUF    | 1-0   |            7 | 16.7%          |               7 | 16.7%             |             17 | 2.6%             |                      17 | 2.6%                      |              7 | -19.0%           |                       7 | -19.0%                    |                   22 | -4.8%                  |                            22 | -4.8%                           |
|  7 | LV     | 1-0   |            8 | 13.7%          |               8 | 13.7%             |              5 | 31.7%            |                       5 | 31.7%                     |             23 | 16.5%            |                      23 | 16.5%                     |                   15 | -1.4%                  |                            15 | -1.4%                           |
|  8 | NO     | 1-0   |            9 | 10.8%          |               9 | 10.8%             |             24 | -13.7%           |                      24 | -13.7%                    |              9 | -14.3%           |                       9 | -14.3%                    |                    1 | 10.2%                  |                             1 | 10.2%                           |
|  9 | MIN    | 0-1   |           10 | 10.8%          |              10 | 10.8%             |              6 | 28.2%            |                       6 | 28.2%                     |             26 | 20.1%            |                      26 | 20.1%                     |                    6 | 2.7%                   |                             6 | 2.7%                            |
| 10 | LAC    | 1-0   |           11 | 4.1%           |              11 | 4.1%              |             22 | -7.6%            |                      22 | -7.6%                     |              6 | -20.4%           |                       6 | -20.4%                    |                   26 | -8.7%                  |                            26 | -8.7%                           |
| 11 | CAR    | 0-1   |           12 | 2.5%           |              12 | 2.5%              |              8 | 23.4%            |                       8 | 23.4%                     |             27 | 24.0%            |                      27 | 24.0%                     |                    4 | 3.2%                   |                             4 | 3.2%                            |
| 12 | CHI    | 1-0   |           13 | 0.3%           |              13 | 0.3%              |             19 | 0.9%             |                      19 | 0.9%                      |             12 | -1.6%            |                      12 | -1.6%                     |                   16 | -2.2%                  |                            16 | -2.2%                           |
| 13 | DAL    | 0-1   |           14 | 0.3%           |              14 | 0.3%              |             12 | 9.2%             |                      12 | 9.2%                      |             18 | 3.9%             |                      18 | 3.9%                      |                   23 | -5.1%                  |                            23 | -5.1%                           |
| 14 | DET    | 0-1   |           15 | -0.1%          |              15 | -0.1%             |             21 | -0.3%            |                      21 | -0.3%                     |             15 | 1.2%             |                      15 | 1.2%                      |                    9 | 1.4%                   |                             9 | 1.4%                            |
| 15 | KC     | 1-0   |           16 | -1.3%          |              16 | -1.3%             |              9 | 17.6%            |                       9 | 17.6%                     |             25 | 17.5%            |                      25 | 17.5%                     |                   14 | -1.3%                  |                            14 | -1.3%                           |
| 16 | GB     | 1-0   |           17 | -5.0%          |              17 | -5.0%             |              7 | 24.2%            |                       7 | 24.2%                     |             30 | 28.7%            |                      30 | 28.7%                     |                   12 | -0.4%                  |                            12 | -0.4%                           |
| 17 | ARI    | 1-0   |           18 | -5.2%          |              18 | -5.2%             |             20 | 0.5%             |                      20 | 0.5%                      |             17 | 2.9%             |                      17 | 2.9%                      |                   17 | -2.8%                  |                            17 | -2.8%                           |
| 18 | SF     | 0-1   |           19 | -6.1%          |              19 | -6.1%             |             18 | 2.3%             |                      18 | 2.3%                      |             14 | 0.6%             |                      14 | 0.6%                      |                   24 | -7.8%                  |                            24 | -7.8%                           |
| 19 | HOU    | 0-1   |           20 | -9.3%          |              20 | -9.3%             |             11 | 11.1%            |                      11 | 11.1%                     |             24 | 16.7%            |                      24 | 16.7%                     |                   19 | -3.6%                  |                            19 | -3.6%                           |
| 20 | LAR    | 1-0   |           21 | -13.5%         |              21 | -13.5%            |             13 | 7.5%             |                      13 | 7.5%                      |             20 | 9.5%             |                      20 | 9.5%                      |                   28 | -11.4%                 |                            28 | -11.4%                          |
| 21 | TEN    | 1-0   |           22 | -14.3%         |              22 | -14.3%            |             16 | 3.4%             |                      16 | 3.4%                      |             10 | -11.1%           |                      10 | -11.1%                    |                   32 | -28.7%                 |                            32 | -28.7%                          |
| 22 | TB     | 0-1   |           23 | -16.3%         |              23 | -16.3%            |             25 | -16.1%           |                      25 | -16.1%                    |              8 | -16.4%           |                       8 | -16.4%                    |                   30 | -16.7%                 |                            30 | -16.7%                          |
| 23 | DEN    | 0-1   |           24 | -17.1%         |              24 | -17.1%            |             23 | -13.3%           |                      23 | -13.3%                    |             19 | 3.9%             |                      19 | 3.9%                      |                   11 | 0.1%                   |                            11 | 0.1%                            |
| 24 | ATL    | 0-1   |           25 | -26.0%         |              25 | -26.0%            |             10 | 11.8%            |                      10 | 11.8%                     |             32 | 38.9%            |                      32 | 38.9%                     |                   10 | 1.1%                   |                            10 | 1.1%                            |
| 25 | IND    | 0-1   |           26 | -27.0%         |              26 | -27.0%            |             15 | 3.8%             |                      15 | 3.8%                      |             28 | 26.0%            |                      28 | 26.0%                     |                   21 | -4.8%                  |                            21 | -4.8%                           |
| 26 | CIN    | 0-1   |           27 | -28.4%         |              27 | -28.4%            |             29 | -33.2%           |                      29 | -33.2%                    |             11 | -8.5%            |                      11 | -8.5%                     |                   20 | -3.7%                  |                            20 | -3.7%                           |
| 27 | NYJ    | 0-1   |           28 | -35.2%         |              28 | -35.2%            |             26 | -21.1%           |                      26 | -21.1%                    |             16 | 2.7%             |                      16 | 2.7%                      |                   29 | -11.4%                 |                            29 | -11.4%                          |
| 28 | PHI    | 0-1   |           29 | -41.1%         |              29 | -41.1%            |             32 | -71.3%           |                      32 | -71.3%                    |              4 | -33.6%           |                       4 | -33.6%                    |                   18 | -3.4%                  |                            18 | -3.4%                           |
| 29 | MIA    | 0-1   |           30 | -48.9%         |              30 | -48.9%            |             27 | -23.2%           |                      27 | -23.2%                    |             29 | 28.3%            |                      29 | 28.3%                     |                    8 | 2.6%                   |                             8 | 2.6%                            |
| 30 | NYG    | 0-1   |           31 | -54.7%         |              31 | -54.7%            |             30 | -45.4%           |                      30 | -45.4%                    |             22 | 11.9%            |                      22 | 11.9%                     |                    7 | 2.6%                   |                             7 | 2.6%                            |
| 31 | CLE    | 0-1   |           32 | -107.6%        |              32 | -107.6%           |             31 | -57.5%           |                      31 | -57.5%                    |             31 | 33.3%            |                      31 | 33.3%                     |                   31 | -16.8%                 |                            31 | -16.8%                          |
```